# Increasing data points in graphite with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, graphite, grafana

I am currently expanding our jmeter load testing project to send data into a carbon/graphite/grafana server.

Jmeter seems to only send metrics once a minute and I'd like to increase that to something like one per five seconds.

I can't find any documentation that tells me how to send more metrics to graphite via jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

try tweaking the value in jmeter.properties file:

```
#summariser.interval=30 // default is 30 seconds. remove # to uncomment and restart the JMeter.
```

Another variable in influxdb config:

```
store-interval = “10s” //default value
```

please refer `[monitor]` section in `infludb.conf`

> The interval at which InfluxDB records statistics.

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.1/administration/config/#enabled-false

Comment: @Avamore, did it work? try store-interval in influxdb.conf file